# How to run a VBA function when running a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation that I would like to enable the editing of the data (text boxes, etc.) even in the middle of the presentation on the screen.

I know that it is possible using a presenter view, where editing is visible directly to the screen, but I would like the user (normal...) not to have to play with the file itself, because this may cause problems besides the inconvenience of it, so I thought of making an Excel file, where the data will be and write A function that will read the data from Excel and put them each in their place in the presentation (on the same idea you can handle objects, etc. using the condition that its true will come from Excel..).

I've already written the function for reading the data from Excel, but I can't figure out how I can make the function run in a loop for the duration of the presentation.

I thought of two methods, both of which I was unable to implement

1. Run a function when the presentation starts and run it in a loop until the presentation ends. But I didn't find how to make the function start running automatically when the presentation is started, and what's more, when I tried to group the function to run after clicking the UserForm button, I can't make a loop there..
2. A timer event that will be activated every 5 seconds and will activate the update function from Excel, and I couldn't find that either, is there such a thing in VBA in PowerPoint..

I would appreciate any help on the subject!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a shape on each slide, then format that shape with **Insert>Links>Action** to run a PowerPoint macro that updates the data from Excel. The shape can be transparent, or the same color as the background, so it doesn't have to be visible on-screen.

You can also create a VBA timer in Excel that runs periodically to update the Excel links. Here is sample code:

```
Sub AutoTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "UpdatePresentation"    'Runs every 10 seconds
End Sub

Sub UpdatePresentation()
    MsgBox "Updating"
    Call AutoTimer
End Sub
```

Another issue, which you haven't noticed yet, because you haven't gotten this running, is that PowerPoint doesn't like to update the presentation while it's running. To fix this, you'll have to add a line of code like this to update the display:

```
Application.SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide Me.SlideIndex
```

Comment: And sometimes that's not even enough to force a redraw of the current slide; if you run into that, it can help to add then remove a shape to the slide. Even a shape off the edge of the slide can be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few presentations that run code automatically while in slideshow mode, and updates can be applied during the presentation when moving from one slide to the next. It uses the 'OnSlideShowPageChange()' sub. Here is a simplified example of what I use:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    
     SlideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    
     If SlideNum = 1 Then

          SlideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).SlideNumber

          For i = 1 to SlideCount     
               'Code I want to run once, such as running through each slide looking for shape names I've established in order to make updates, such as updating to the current date.
          Next i

     Else
          Select Case ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideID
               Case "[Slide ID]"
                    'Code I want to run based on the specific slide I'm on.
                    'Using Slide ID instead of Slide Index since ID doesn't change when other slides are added or removed.
          End Select
      End If
    
End Sub
```

You probably already have it in place, but I'm heavily relying on the use of the Selection Pane and naming the objects on the slide in order to then locate objects that need to be updated.

While I have not experimented with pulling real-time data to continually update a displayed slide, perhaps triggering code on each slide change may help get you what you are looking for.